# Qty order Decimals

Tags: magento-1.8, product

Hi how can i remove decimals to not show  for qty in my xml file i'm using this code to show qty $item->getQtyOrdered() i already have tried with product no Decimals from the adim in catalorg product but not working

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use any php function to strip the decimals:

- http://de3.php.net/number_format
- http://de3.php.net/sprintf
- http://de3.php.net/round
- http://de3.php.net/floor